# Angular2 http service to replace with custom service

Tags: angular

I think it can be common problem for many other developers, but I didn't found some efficient solution yet.

I'm working on Angular2 project. Of course I have many places when I need to make http calls to manage my data. So I'm using `Http` service and everything works as expected.

On some architecture stage (when team have implemented most of pages), new requirement comes into place - now we need to connect deeper our server and client so additional header should be added to all requests initiated from client (it can be authenticated bearer token, method override instruction to pass firewall, many other).

Not a problem at all. 10 min to accomplish:

- creating new service `MyHttp`
- re-imlementing all `get`, `post`, `put`, `delete` methods with adding required headers
- mass replace all `Http` references with new `MyHttp`
- work done

But this approach is not good when you have many developers involved:

- Some wiki resource should be created and defined new rules with accessing server. All developers from all teams should start follow this rules immediately
- There is a risk that old `Http` service instead of `MyHttp` will be re-used as both services are accessible, so incorrect behavior will be introduced
- More pain for server team to find incorrect behavior when incorrect client http service was chosen

So more suitable approach for multi-team development - is to use `@NgModule` module class annotation to replace old `Http` service with new `MyHttp` using `provide` configuration:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [..., {provide: Http, useClass: MyHttp}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

From my point of view this approach has many advantages:

- no need to modify files and replace `Http` to `MyHttp`
- no need to change developer rules in using `Http` service
- assure that server side always receive proper headers
- no worry about incidentally using `MyHttp` instead of `Http` - they behave equally

The only problem, that we are creating cyclic dependency as inside `MyHttp` we need to use old `Http`

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  get(url: string) { return this.http.get(url); }
  post(url: string, data: any) { ...}
  ...
}
```

So exception is thrown:

> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!

So the only way - is to create `MyHttp` totally independent from `Http`. But it adds more complexity to code. And such kind of implementation smell, to be honest.

Is any solutions how to use `Http` inside `MyHttp` using configuration defined above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyHttp extends Http {

}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ HttpModule, ... ],
  providers: [..., 
    {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: XhrBackend},
    {provide: Http, useClass: MyHttp}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

no need to inject HTTP this way.

Just override from https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5921c872b6ef2f2de31f90576660a1bf56afb979/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts#L103-L184 what you want to have different behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Trying to refactor my code, but I always receive exception `No provider for ConnectionBackend!` even having `HttpModule` defined in module imports.

Comment: They are using a weird way to provide `Http` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14ee75924b6ae770115f7f260d720efa8bfb576a/modules/%40angular/http/src/http_module.ts#L49. You need to add the `ConnectionBackend` provider yourself. See my updated answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work :)