# Append header to all Http Requests -> Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I need the equivalent of the interceptor in Angular 1.x.
I found a lot of solutions in old questions, but apparently they are not working anymore!

Can you provide a solution that works with the latest release of Angular 2?

Comment: Have a look: [41998690](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998690/angular2-http-service-to-replace-with-custom-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override Angular's `Http` class, add headers there and then provide `CustomHttp` class in your modules:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { RequestOptionsArgs, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Http, Request, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {

headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Something': 'Something' });
options1: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
}

get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
    console.log('Custom get...');
    return super.get(url, this.options1).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
}
```

You need to do the same for `post`, `put`, `delete` etc.
And in your module:

```
{ provide: Http, 
    useFactory: (
        backend: XHRBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions) =>
        new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks man! I only needed the last part (how to declare the new service in the NgModule), and it worked immediatly!

Comment: @Nano Glad I could be of assistance, please consider marking my answer as accepted if it helped you. :)